# Byzantine fault tolerance (BFT) and Crash fault tolerance (CFT)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Crash fault tolerance (CFT) is one level of resiliency, where the system can still correctly reach consensus if components fail. While Byzantine fault tolerance (BFT), which says the orderer can do its job even in the presence of malicious actors. Below are my questions

1. CFT is more useful for single enterprise. Presently Hyperleger Fabric uses Kafka which is CFT. Even in the case of multiple organization we are using Kafka in Hyperledger Fabric network. Does it mean still we are using CFT?
2. In CFT, How system can still correctly reach consensus if components fail? For example network is down, or malcious node present in system etc
3. Can CFT work even in presence of malicious actor?
4. How Hyperledger Fabric implements BFT? When will they release it?
5. What is the main difference between CFT & BFT?

Answer (score 16):

> 1. CFT is more useful for single enterprise. Presently Hyperleger Fabric uses Kafka which is CFT. Even in the case of multiple organization we are using Kafka in Hyperledger Fabric network. Does it mean still we are using CFT?

Yes it's still CFT, Crash Fault Tolerant model guaranties to withstand system failures, such as crashes, network partitioning. Having N nodes in your consensus system CFT capable to withstand up to N/2 such crashes. Fact that you might distribute it across organizations or different clouds won't change this assumption.

> 2. In CFT, How system can still correctly reach consensus if components fail? For example network is down, or malcious node present in system etc

In CFT model there is quorum of N/2 + 1 nodes which has to agree on certain value, therefore as long as you have N/2 + 1 nodes available, which means you have a quorum you will be able to reach agreement, since majority agrees on it. And *NO* it cannot guarantee anything in presence of malicious actors.

> 3. Can CFT work even in presence of malicious actor?

Nope.

> 4. How Hyperledger Fabric implements BFT? When will they release it?

There is a plan to implement BFT protocol and integrate in into Fabric, however exact days currently under carefully design and planning. I guess it will be reveled at one of the bi-weekly maintainers meetings.

> 5. What is the main difference between CFT & BFT?

The key difference is in the assumptions and threat/failure model, CFT can withstand up to N/2 system failures, while no guarantees on adversary nodes. BFT provides with guarantees to withstand and correctly reach consensus in presence of N/3 failures of any kind including Byzantine. You can think of it as two phase commit versus three phase commit.